# I want to create a Fibonacci sequence using a for loop, but the integers are not adding up

Tags: delphi, fibonacci

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  term1: integer;
  term2: integer;
  term3: integer;
  j: integer;
begin
  term1 := (0);
  term2 := (1);
  for j := 1 to 100 do;
  begin
    term3 :=( term1 + term2);
    Memo1.Text:=inttostr(term3);

    term1 := term2;
    term2 := term3;
  end;
end;

end.
```

This is what I have so far, but `term1` and `term2` don't want to add up. I have tried some different things, but for some reason the integers never want to add up.

Comment: `for j := 1 to 100 do` iterates the statement immediately following `do` (for example, `for j := 1 to 100 do Beep;` or `for j := 1 to 100 do ShowMessage(j.ToString);`). In your example, this is the empty statement (`for j := 1 to 100 do {nothing here!};`). So you do absolutely nothing 100 times. If you remove the semicolon after `do`, the statement immediately following `do` will be the `begin ... end` block. That's what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code

1. The semicolon after `for j := 1 to 100 do` prevents your next code that is withing `begin..end` block to be run in a loop. Why? The code that is to be run in each cycle of `for loop` is the one that follows the `do` until the first semicolon. Since you put semicolon just after the `do` this basically means that empty block of code is ran in a loop. Your `begin..end` block comes after that. Removing the semicolon after `do` will fix that.
2. You are using `Memo1.Text:=inttostr(term3);` to write the result into Memo. The problem with this is that this will rewrite entire text of the Memo every time so you will end up with only one line showing the last number. You should use `Memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr(term3));` instead so that new line is added each time.
3. Lastly you are using [Integer](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Integer) type for your variables. Since numbers in Fibonacci sequence grows very fast you will quickly exceed the maximum value that can be stored in Integer which in Delphi is **Signed 32 bit Integer** with a max value of 2147483647. You will have to use bigger integer types like 64 bit Integer type and since you are only dealing with positive numbers you should therefore use **Unsigned 64 bit Integer** that in declared in Delphi by [UInt64](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.UInt64) type. You can read more about Delphi default Integer types in [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Integer_Types). Unfortunately not even `UInt64` will is big enough for value of all first 100 numbers of Fibonacci sequence. So you will have to use one of the **BigIntegers** libraries for Delphi to do this properly. There are several of them available on internet.

Answer (score 1):

You have an erroneous `;` on your loop that you need to remove:

```
for j := 1 to 100 do;
                    ^
```

Comment: In other words: you have to question your understanding of what a semicolon's purpose is - and it is definitly not just "there". You also refrained from appending them after `var` and `begin` - but why only there and not with `do`, too?